# Integration tests fails if run via maven, but passes if run via IDE

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, cucumber

I have an acceptance test module that does an ejb call to another module. But for this acceptance test, I don't want it call the ejb directly as this may cause my tests to be very slow. So to over come that, I used `SimpleNamingContextBuilder` to mock the JNDI call. For my acceptance test, I am using `Cucumber`framework.

I created my own annotation `@mockJNDIServices`, the java method that does the JNDI looks like

> ```
> @Before("@MockJndiEntityService")
> public void mockJndiService() throws NamingException {
>     final EjbServiceRemote ejbService = new EjbServiceRemoteStubImpl();
>     final SimpleNamingContextBuilder contextBuilder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
>
>     contextBuilder.bind(EjbServiceRemote.EJB_NAME, ejbService);
>     contextBuilder.activate();
> }
> ```

`EjbServiceRemoteStubImpl` is a stub I would like tests to call instead of the service itself.

and the feature file has the heading

```
@MockJndiEntityService
@transaction
Feature: Lookups from library of policy
```

When I run this code via the IDE (`Intellij`), it works fine and everything passes.
But when I run it through the build tool (`Maven`), I get the remote lookup failure

> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [ejb/EjbServiceEJB#ejb.service.EjbServiceRemote]
>   not bound; 1 bindings:
>   [ejb/EjbServiceEJB#ejb.service.EjbServiceRemote

It seems like the annotation is not being applied for each feature/scenarios.

Has anyone ever came across this? your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you maybe need to `mvn clean test` instead of just `mvn test`?

Comment: Test if the maven and java versions are the same in both environments

Comment: Another potential cause of this is one test is depending on another test's completion (i.e. one test dirties the environment.) And it may be a test from another test class. In IDEA, try running all the tests (via the context menu on the root `test` directory) and see if a test fails like it does in Maven.

Comment: Thanks guys. The issue was that "EjbServiceRemote.EJB_NAME" had an extra space.